# 'pre_doctype' does not contain a definition for 'AttributeLogicalNames'

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, xrm, xrmtoolbox

I'm new to C#, the Dynamics CRM SDK and new to the XrmToolbox. I just got thrown into a project which was developed by an external company and now I'm trying to add something to the project.

So, I created my new Entity in CRM and used the XrmToolbox to generate my Entity class files. When I try to access the early bound entities the same way it's done everywhere else in the code, I get a red squiggly for AttributeLogicalNames. The generated file created a `public static class Fields` instead of a `public class AttributeLogicalNames`

I could just use "Fields", but I would rather keep the coding consistent.

Can I set this somewhere in the XrmToolbox? Or can I fix this some other way, so I can still access "AttributeLogicalNames" and keep the generated file untouched?

Comment: My advice is that is better to work with late bound fields, you don't need to generate anything aditional code.